# Entity Framework Many-To-Many + Count

Tags: c#, linq, entity-framework, linq-to-entities

I have three tables, Professors, ProfessorStudent, Student.

I want all Professors + How many Students each Professor have.

I can do this:

```
context.ProfessorSet.Include("Student")
```

context.ProfessorSet.Include("Student").ToList() will read all three tables.

But i dont wanna get Student table, I want that Linq just get "Professor Table"+ "Count(*) ProfessorStudent Group By StudentId".

Its possible?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I do using this:

```
        var c = from tag in contexto.ProfessorSet
                select new
                {
                    Tag = tag,
                    Count = tag.Student.Count
                };
```

But generate this SQL:

SELECT 
C.Id,
C.Nome,
C.C1
FROM
    (SELECT 
        A.Id,
        A.Nome,
        (SELECT 
            COUNT(0)
            FROM ProfessorStudant AS B
            WHERE A.Id = B.ProfessorId
        ) AS [C1]
    FROM Professor AS A)

I want this:

Select A.Id, Count(0) from Professor A
inner join ProfessorStudent B on A.Id = B.ProfessorId
Group By A.Id

Answer (score 0):

```
from p in context.ProfessorSet
from s in p.Student
group s by s.StudentId into g
select new
{
    Professor = p,
    StudentCounts = from sc in g
                    select new
                    {
                        StudentId = sc.Key,
                        Count = sc.Group.Count()
                    }
}
```

Comment: Error on lines

Professor = p,

Cannot resolve symbol p

And Count = sc.Count()

Count() dont exists